# Decrease nested loops quantity

Tags: c

Below is the code where I have to check a specific character in substring of string. How can I decrease its complexity, as I use three `for` loops but want to do it in two or one loop?

```c
int main(void) {
    int i, j, k, t, n;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        int count = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        char a[n], ch;
        scanf("%s %c", a, &ch);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                    if (a[k] == ch) {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly ?

Comment: In what substring are you supposed to search the character?

Comment: I think I've worked out what you are trying to do but it took two tries and help from NellieDanielyan.  If your asking a question like this one it really helps if you explain what your trying to achieve, if people can't easily identify the problem then you'll get less help. So something like the 1st paragraph in my answer that shows an input and the expected results will improve things next time you ask.

Comment: This could be a really nice and good question, but it should be rephrased better, with a good MCVE and a good number of example inputs and outputs. The whole minimal reproducible function could look like `int function(const char *a, char ch)` and it should return the number of times the character `ch` occurs in all possible substrings of string `a`. The problem is really good and I can't find a good algorithm if the character occurs more then one time in the string.

Answer (score 0):

So what it looks like from your code is that your trying to generate a set of substrings, so if your array was `abc` then the substrings would be `a, ab, abc, b, bc, c`. You then try and count the number of times a character appears, so if `ch = 'b'` then the result would be 4.  So you are counting the number of strings that contain ch.

So one way to solve this problem with fewer loops would be to recognise for each value of `i` you create the strings by adding a character to the last string, and if the previous string contained `n` copies of `ch` then the next string contains `n` or `n+1` copies depending on the actual value.

Another possible approach to get down to just one loop would be loop through the array once and each time you find the character `ch` calculate how many sub-strings will contain the character at that position. So for the `abc` example 2 of the 3 strings starting at position 0 and 2 of the strings starting at position 1 will contain the value.

Comment: Looks to me like number of substring containing it. There is a `break` statement. Once it hits the char, it goes on to the next substring.

Comment: @NellieDanielyan. I think your right.  The break makes it the number of sub-strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memchr` instead of the most inner loop.

Substitute

```
            for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                if (a[k] == ch) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

for

```
  if (memchr(&a[i], ch, j - i + 1) != NULL) {
      count++;
  }
```

This will make you use two loops in your code.